# How to segue from a xib to a viewcontroller from a storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift

I'd like to combine two different Xcode projects. One uses a `xib` file and the second uses a `storyboard`. After adding the appropriate files to the existing project, how can it be so that the `xib` knows about the `storyboard` so that a segue be made using a button from the xib to a different view controller in the storyboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create new view controller and inside the class load the xib by code. in ViewDidload

```
let popupView  = DropDownView.init(frame: self.view.frame)
self.view.addSubview(popupView)
```

or add a view inside the new ViewController and assign the xib class to it.